# MapView rotation / orientation issue

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-orientation

I am working on MapActivity that have some extra fields in top, bottom and side of the the map. These all View component is available in a single main.xml file. For both orientation i have layout-land and for portrait directory also, both folder containing main.xml with same ids.

I have use android:ConfigChaneg in androidManifest.xml, and i overrides the method **onConfigChange(Configuration newConfig)**

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

But now when screen is rotating / changing orientation then getting Exception. **MapActivity can have only one MapView** how to solve this problem,  Please guide me.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

here if you want to fix in one mode screen you may fix screen in Manifest file 
in activity add attribute android:screenOrientation="portrait"
or here when your onConfigurationChanged here start all process again in both mode

Comment: you need to both Orientation ?